# How to get the community license of Syncfusion?

Tags: maui, syncfusion

Recently, I am learning MAUI and I wanna use the UI from Syncfusion.

I tried to get the community license of it, and I followed the steps from the Syncfusion site. But there was no responding after I login with my LinkedIn account.
Guys, if you know something about this, could you please give me some suggestions or tell me if the community license is not available for applying?
Or maybe you can recommend some else good and free UI library for MAUI to me. Much thanks!

Comment: did you ask syncfusion?

Comment: Do you see your name in the up right corner

Comment: Do you mean the account of Syncfusion? Yes, I can see my name in the up-right corner. @BasH

Comment: Yep. the Syncfusion UI library in https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/communitylicense @SirRufo

Comment: Then click on Get License Key or Get unlock key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [Syncfusion.com](https://www.syncfusion.com/)

Sign in top right corner

Select PRICING - and the Communitylicense. Then click Claim your free license.
Get License or Unlock Key , or download them (best option) so you cannot lose it .
Don't forget to set `the key in App.xaml.cs`

[image]

[image]

[image]